# where does Transport struct in net/http/transport.go implement RoudTripper interface

Tags: go

RoundTripper interface is like

```
type RoundTripper interface {
    RoundTrip(*Request) (*Response, error)
}
```

and inside [net/http/transport.go](https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go) I can only find an function named roundTrip(which is lowercase), so I wonder where does this struct Transport implement RoundTripper interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is in https://golang.org/src/net/http/roundtrip.go instead of https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go.

To see this you can try this playground and its output - https://play.golang.org/p/A97ylJmc43R

The code was in https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go, but was later refactored out in https://github.com/golang/go/commit/b12e341616365cafd6f7eab9aaaa29c4155c1a76#diff-e85f2dbad3447c4267e815cc9d014e69.

(Speculation - do not trust it 100%) From the commit description and the issue (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25506), it seems that the refactor was for using the Fetch API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in the WebAssembly backend ([build flags](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/b12e341616365cafd6f7eab9aaaa29c4155c1a76#diff-e85f2dbad3447c4267e815cc9d014e69R5)). Since this would only work for WASM, the code was refactored to split out the two separate implementations.

Comment: just one more question, why they refactor this function out, I find in the link "add js/wasm compatible DefaultTransport" , why should this refactor be needed???

Comment: @AlanLian - Updated and added some speculations.